# How to upload Verification HTML file to my Google Sites website?

Tags: google-search-console, google-sites

I created a simple website using Google Sites. Using Google's webmaster central, I need to upload an html file to the google site I created to verify that I own the website.

However, upon numerous trial and error. It seems it cannot work for me. Has anyone tried to verify any of their Google sites to Google webmaster central?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use the verification HTML file with a Google Sites website. Instead, new Google Sites will verify automatically, and old Google Sites should use the HTML tag, not HTML file.

> New Google Sites pages that you create should automatically appear and be verified in your Search Console account. If your site doesn't appear automatically on the Search Console home page, click Add a site. Your site will be verified automatically.
>
> Older sites or sites with a custom domain URL should be verified using the HTML tag method.
>
> Note that your site must be created using the same Google Account you use for Search Console.

[Verify your site ownership - Google Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179)

Comment: The background here is that I am requesting for OAUTH authentication via Google. In the OAUTH Consent Screen I need to I need to specify the home page  and privacy policy links. I am unable to do so with the google site I created. When I go to the Domain Verification area of the Google Credentials section it forces me to upload an html file or metatag to the google site i created